# Gnuplot: how to use logarithmic scale in the legend

Tags: gnuplot, colorbox, legend

I want to use a legend with logarithmic scale.

Here is the test code:

```
set pm3d;
set pm3d map;
splot x*y;
```

It gives:

[image]

I want to have a legend with logarithmic scale like this:

[image]

Is it possible in Gnuplot?

Another relevant questions is how can I set the number of tics in the legend.

Normally I can get 1,10,100, what if I want to have 1,2,4,8,16,32,.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `set logscale <axes> {base}`, e.g.:

```
set pm3d
set pm3d map
set logscale cb
splot x*y
```

The color box scale can be changed to base 2 with:

```
set cbtics 2
```

Note: when logarithmic scale is in effect the increment argument to `set cbtics` is used as a multiplicative instead of an additive.

The above taken together and plotted in a more logarithmically reasonable domain could for example look like this:

```
set pm3d
set pm3d map
set logscale cb
set cbtics 2
splot [1:8] [1:8] x*y
```

Which results in:

[image: Image showing use of logarithmic scale and base two tics]